# Can I use cuda without using nvcc on my host code?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I'm writing a single header library that executes a cuda kernel. I was wondering if there is a way to get around the <<<>>> syntax, or get C source output from nvcc?

Comment: You can avoid having to call the nvcc by compiling your kernel into a CUBIN or PTX file, and load and execute this with the driver API, eventually replacing the `<<<...>>>` syntax call of the runtime API with a call to [`cuLaunchKernel`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15). (If this is sufficient, I'd elaborate it a bit and convert it to an answer)

Comment: The one sentence answer is "use the CUDA driver API".

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the host language extensions by using the CUDA [driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api) instead. It is a little more verbose and you will require a little more boilerplate code to manage the context,  but it is not too difficult.

Conventionally, you would compile to PTX or a binary payload to load at runtime, however NVIDIA now also ship an experimental JIT CUDA C compiler library, [libNVVM](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/libnvvm-api/index.html#axzz3zsc1A4LN), which you could try if you want JIT from source.

Comment: If one still wants to rely on the runtime API is not not enough to: use cuLaunchKernel in host code, manually include the right runtime headers, use nvcc to link the device and host code?

Comment: @pszilard: No. The runtime API relies on lots of nvcc generated boilerplate and several undocumented API calls to make lazy context initialization work. If you don't use nvcc to compile, you don't get that and nothing will work. Unless you use the driver API and explicitly manage the context and modules yourself.